# Displaying a tooltip with PHP object's properties using jQuery Tooltip Plugin (or any other method)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I can't get my head around this issue. I have some PHP objects and I'm using 'echo' to display it on HTML page like this;

```
echo '<td><table border="1" width="55" height="55"><tr><td><img src="' . $Schema->result->item->image_url . '"/></td></tr></table></td>';
```

**What I want to do is if I hover over that image, it should display a new small window (tooltip) with `"$Schema->result->level"`**

I'm using this to display tooltip; http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/ (tonus)

But I have no idea how to pass the PHP variables to JQuery function.

*To sum up, I'm looking for a way to display an object's variable in a new window when I hover over an image.*

---

Am I doing this all wrong? I finished codecademy.com 's lessons and I'm still getting stuck on simple problems like this, any advices on that?

Thanks all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Add id `#tonus` to image tag( `<img` ) and add `$Schema->result->level` to `title` attribute

```
echo '<td><table border="1" width="55" height="55"><tr><td><img id="tonus" src="' . $Schema->result->item->image_url . ' title="'.$Schema->result->level .'"/></td></tr></table></td>';
```

Js:

```
<script>
$('#tonus').tooltip({ 
    delay: 0, 
    showURL: false
});
</script>
```

Comment: What if I need to display a second value? Anything else I can use other than 'title'?

Comment: yes use `rel` and `data-` attribute and change the js accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Could I suggest using the [JQueryUI tooltip](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/) library then? All you would need to do there is output your data into the `title` attribute and then instanciate the tooltip library on load.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear, I edited the question a bit.

Comment: What if I need to display a second value? Anything else I can use other than 'title'?

Comment: You could reference other attributes if needed for your original script (not sure UI supports anything other than title). Use the `attr` function http://api.jquery.com/attr/